# Fastest way of norming vectors in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, benchmarking, normalization

I'd like to sort out what it the fastest way to get the norm of a set of vectors contained in a matrix. I was using `apply` (this is an example, my matrices are much bigger):

```
a = matrix(1:9, 3,3)
norm_a = apply(a, 1, function(x) sqrt(sum(x^2)))
```

but then I wanted to speed up my code and moved to:

```
norm_a = sqrt(a^2%*%rep(1,dim(a)[2]))
```

which is actually much faster (seen with `system.time`, I'm not an expert in benchmarking). But I haven't found any final answer to this question so far. Does anyone have an insight about this ?

thanks

Comment: what about using function `norm` ?

Comment: `norm` is to calcul the norm of a matrix, not the (euclidian) norm of a set of vector. I could use it together with `apply` and `type = "F"` but it seems to be almost the same as my first attempt with `sqrt(sum(x^2))`

Comment: I meant `apply(a,1,norm,"2")` (not necessarily faster, just more parcimonious as code)

Comment: from the 3 possibilities and based on a `300x300` matrix, your second option is the fastest, then your 1st one, then the `norm` option (results from `microbenchmark` function, from the `microbenchmark` package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the size of your matrix:

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(f1 = apply(a, 1, function(x) sqrt(sum(x^2))),
               f2 = sqrt(a^2%*%rep(1,dim(a)[2])),
               f3 = sqrt(rowSums(a^2)))
#Unit: microseconds
# expr    min     lq     mean  median      uq     max neval cld
#   f1 44.656 46.812 52.21050 47.5815 49.4295 191.248   100   c
#   f2  1.849  2.772  4.07532  4.3120  4.6210  16.323   100 a  
#   f3  6.160  7.392  9.25537  9.5480 10.1630  20.943   100  b 

set.seed(42)
b <- matrix(rnorm(1e6), 1000)

microbenchmark(f1 = apply(b, 1, function(x) sqrt(sum(x^2))),
               f2 = sqrt(b^2%*%rep(1,dim(b)[2])),
               f3 = sqrt(rowSums(b^2)))
#Unit: milliseconds
# expr       min        lq     mean     median        uq       max neval cld
#   f1 30.851752 55.513228 86.84168 109.439043 112.54796 152.27730   100   b
#   f2  5.503050  7.434152 14.36080   8.861268  10.42327  66.41539   100  a 
#   f3  4.430403  5.895553 12.92235   7.359163   8.62321  74.65256   100  a
```

Comment: interesting results, and so in any case using `f2` is a conservative choice